# Weighted mean in attribute union with QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have joined Argentina's census data wich has small area divisions, with electoral disctrict data wich has a bigger area than those of the census. In QGIS, I've calculated centroids for the census data and joined through the "join attribute by location (summary) tool".

Census data i aggregated to get the population in electoral disctrict, but i've found no way to caculate a census index which i would want to take to the electoral level by doin a weighted average:

```
(sum (index * total_pop)) / sum(total_pop)
```

The question sums as:
Is there a way to add a statistic function (a user edited one) to the spatial join of the census centroids to the electoral disctrict polygons?
[image: This are the two layers i have]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have a polygon layer called `district` and a point layer `census` with attributes named `index`, `pop` (for population) and `id` for the polygon feature from the layer `district` that the point is within. To calculate for each district separately the sum of `pop` muliplied by `index`, use this expression:

```
sum( index*pop, group_by:=id)
```

---

In case you don't yet have an attribute `id` that links to the district the the census-centroid is in, create it using `Join attribute by location` or by creating a new field with field calculator and this expression (instead of `name` use any attribute name of the district layer - or `$id` if you have no attributes there):

```
array_first (overlay_within( 'districts', name))
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer.
The problem though is that there is no "id" columns. (or rather, the id's are not matchable).
So the only way i can do the join is spatialy.
The workaround i have right now is selecting each district, the census points within and manually calculating that through field caclulator. but it's kind of tiresome.

Comment: Why are the id's not matchable? It can be any kind of attribute - the one you created by `join attribute by location` - that's what I understood. If not net done, create it.

Comment: ohh, i se your point. I'm going to try that! 
Thanks!